# How to filter html table using javascript without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these codes already working using plain javascript and got it in W3schools which filtering table data using input text. I added a Select dropdown for filtering table. I've found some answers here but its not working to my codes.

I tried using Jquery but its not working. JQUERY CDN is located at the header

```
 <head>
   <script 
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
   </script>
  </head>

   <table class="table table-bordered" id = "tbl_main_content">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th style = "display: none;">Description</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th style = "display: none;">Status</th>
                <th width="400px">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>

 //my input
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt_list_search" 
 placeholder="Enter keyword..."  onkeyup="myFunction()">

 //my select
<select class="form-control" id = "sort">
<option >Select Sort</option>
<option value = "HTML">Html</option>
<option value = "JAVASCRIPT">Javascript</option>
<option value = "CSS">Css</option>
<option value = "PHP">PHP</option>
<option value = "LARAVEL">Laravel</option>
<option value = "AJAX">Ajax</option>
</select>

 <script>
   function myFunction() 
    {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue; 
    input = document.getElementById("txt_list_search");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("tbl_main_content");   
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");  
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++)
        {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) 
                {
                    txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)
                        {
                            tr[i].style.display = "";
                        } else {
                                 tr[i].style.display = "none";
                                }
                }       
        }
    }

   var options = $("#sort");
   $("#tbl_main_content tr:not(.header)").each(function() {
   options.append($("<option />").val($(this).find("td:first- 
   child").text()).text($(this).find("td:first-child").text()));
   });

   $("#txt_list_search").on('input', function() {
   myFunction($(this).val());
   });

   $("#sort").on('change', function() {
   myFunction($(this).val());
   });
   </script>

     // AJAX METHOD TO DISPLAY DATA FROM DB
     <script>
     getPageData();
     function getPageData() {
     $.ajax({
     dataType: 'json',
     url: url,
     data: {page:page}
     }).done(function(data){
     manageRow(data);
         });
     }

     function manageRow(data) {
     console.log(data)
     var    rows = '';
     $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
     rows = rows + '<tr>';
     if(value.status == 0){
     rows = rows + '<td style = "color: #FF0000">'+value.title+'</td>';
     } else{
     rows = rows + '<td style = "color: #000">'+value.title+'</td>';
     }
     rows = rows + '<td style = "display: none;">'+value.details+'</td>';
     rows = rows + '<td>'+value.category+'</td>';
     rows = rows + '<td style = "display: none;">'+value.status+' </td>';
     rows = rows + '<td data-id="'+value.id+'">';
     rows = rows + '<a href = my-posts-sub/'+value.id+'><button class="btn 
     btn-secondary manage-sub-item"><img src="/media/icon_manage.png" 
     width = "20">&nbsp&nbsp<i>Manage Sub</i></button> </a>';
     rows = rows + '<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-item" 
     class="btn btn-secondary edit-item"><img src="/media/icon_edit.png" 
     width = "20">&nbsp&nbsp<i>Edit</i></button> ';
     rows = rows + '<button class="btn btn-secondary remove-item"><img 
     src="/media/icon_delete.png" width = "20"></button>';
     //---------------------class------bootstrap--variable
     rows = rows + '</td>';
     rows = rows + '</tr>';
     });

     $("tbody").html(rows);

     }
      </script>
```

Comment: @User, where are your table content because it's, throws error  **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null** you are used in script `tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");` please check in **console log error**

Comment: I updated my post sir. As you can see, The method is ajax to display data from db. Why its not working with select dropdown while the input text works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onchange event for select is passing value of the select as an argument to myFunction, but myFunction is not accepting any arguments.  Change myFunction to

```
 function myFunction(filter) 
    {  

    if (filter == undefined)
        filter = document.getElementById("txt_list_search").value.toUpperCase();

    var table = document.getElementById("tbl_main_content");   
    var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");  
    for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++)
        {
            var td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) 
                {
                    var txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1)
                    {
                        tr[i].style.display = "";
                    } else {
                        tr[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                }       
          }
    }
```